# How does Buddhism and Jainism contrast with each other on way of attaining enlightenment?

Tags: philosophy

Jainism is a philosophy which is similar to Buddhism.

So how do Buddhist teachings and the Jains teachings contrast with each other on way of attaining enlightenment ?

Comment: Moderators, is this on topic?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov yes, because it is about Buddhism

Comment: I suspect this may get negative towards another religion. Putting on hold until I hear from other moderators.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov who will this get negative towards other religions, in reality Buddhist scholar have critized jainism. So what's wrong is asking about it. I am not mocking jainism but I want to know what are the arguments  Buddhist scholars make against jain philosophy as both of them are *nastika* philosophy (I. E reject vedas) but believe in reincarnation, karma, Moksha( liberation from the cycle of life and death) and ahimsa(non volince)

Comment: @Andrei Volkov - it's well known that the Buddha had various [peaceful and friendly dialogues](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN56.html) with the Jains. Personally, I think the question is valid although the OP's use of the term *argument* may not be the best of choice words.

Comment: @NeuroMax what word can I use. Because argument means "a reason or the reasoning given for or against a matter under discussion" so I think my word choices is correct.

Comment: Argument in my culture refers to a heated and angry dialogue.

Comment: @NeuroMax can you tell what word can I use.

Comment: Iv'e edited your question. If you're not happy with it, please change it. ;-)

Comment: @NeuroMax thanks for the nice edit. :-)

Comment: Another problem with this question is that it is over broad. One can find many resources on the internet that discuss Jainism and Buddhism and compare and contrast. I don't think this forum is the proper place to answer such a broad question. If the OP can narrow it down to specific points, then perhaps that would help.

Comment: @YesheTenley what kind of specific point I can make.

Comment: If after availing yourself of all the resources out there on the internet about Jainism and Buddhism... after learning about the basics of each and some of the distinguishing features of each... after taking some time to think about those distinguishing features and what they mean... if you then have some question(s) about specific features and how they differ or do not understand some points, then perhaps this forum would be a good place to ask. But as it stands I don't think this forum is a good place for such a *broad* effort to compare/contrast.

Comment: If you want you might even start by typing 'jainism' into the search bar above and see the questions/answers that have already been proffered on Jainism on this site.

Comment: @YesheTenley on way of attaining  enlightened

Comment: Reopened the question, let's give it a shot?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I think it's ok because we also have other questions on Hinduism/ Brahmanism. And it makes sense, because in the Buddha's time, he or his disciples interacted with followers of Brahmanism and Jainism, and there are historical records of these discussions in the Pali Canon.

Comment: Agreed. I was mostly worried about specific wording in the original version of the question.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I think "What some of the main difference between Buddhist doctrine and Jain" needn't be considered overly hostile (i.e. inviting negativity), nor off-topic (i.e. not about Buddhism). However "broad comparisons" were defined as unwelcome in the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) -- and this is broad, not about any specific detail -- the main arguments against broad being that "questions which devolve into broad comparison tend to lead to discussion, rather than to finite answers that are expert and balanced".

Comment: Anyway I think this question or ones very like it have been asked and answered before -- this could be reopened if it were more specific, asking about some detail which might distinguish it from previous questions.

Comment: The typical approach here is to look over the duplicate questions and if you feel they don't answer your question, then update this question being mindful to include specifics. From what I know of the of Buddha and his disciples and how they interacted with the Jains, it's difficult to define those interactions as *broad* because they were mostly centred around self and middle way teachings - which is something we all struggle with from time to time. That might help you narrow down your question a little. ;-)